# SQLAlchemy - как лучше `MetaData` или `__tablename__`?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Встречаются разные способы создания объектов для описания базы в SQLAlchemy.
[Тут](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_quick_guide.htm) с использованием `MetaData`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
meta = MetaData()

students = Table(
   'students', meta, 
   Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True), 
   Column('name', String), 
   Column('lastname', String), 
)
```

А, например,  [тут](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one) - без `MetaData`, а с использованием  `__tablename__` :

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()    

class Parent(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'parent'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

В чем разница? Какой способ использовать лучше, современнее, безопаснее?
И почему существуют оба способа? Какой из них устарел?

Ведь случается, когда используют обе нотации, как например при описании связи [Many to Many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) :

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child",
                    secondary=association_table)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Почему в последнем (дополнительном) примере обе нотации одновременно? То есть нотация без Table и MetaData более ограниченная и "не все" кмеет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует классический подход создания объектов. Это как раз тот, который напрямую использует `mapper()`. А есть декларативный, более лаконичный стиль, с использованием функции `declarative_base()`, который так же использует `mapper()`, но уже не явно.

В документации [написано](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings):

> В некоторых примерах в документации все еще используется классический подход, но следует отметить, что как классический, так и декларативный подходы полностью взаимозаменяемы. В конечном итоге обе системы создают одну и ту же конфигурацию, состоящую из пользовательского класса `Table`, связанного вместе с помощью `mapper()`. Когда мы говорим о «поведении `mapper()`», это относится и к использованию декларативной системы - она ​​все еще используется, просто за кулисами.

Там же не явно указано на то, что классический подход является устаревшим. Например:

> Декларативное отображение - это типичный способ построения отображений в современной SQLAlchemy.

Удобство в декларативном подходе в том, что вся метаинформация и дополнительные атрибуты, такие как связи с другими классами, также объявляются встроенными в определение класса. Так же классический подход не поддерживает систему *"string lookup"* и к полям таблицы необходимо обращаться, как: `table_name.c.field_name`.

Императивный подход удобнее использовать для описания таблиц связей, именно так и поступает `sqlacodegen`.
Из документации [построение связей](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html):

> Для построения связи *Many to Many* добавляется таблица связи между
>   двумя классами. Таблица ассоциаций указывается `вторичным` аргументом
>   для `relationship()`. Обычно в `Table` используется объект `MetaData`,
>   связанный с декларативным базовым классом, так что директивы
>   `ForeignKey` могут найти удаленные таблицы, с которыми можно связать:

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", secondary=association_table)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Насколько я понимаю это связано с тем, что параметру функции `relationship()` мы должны передать структуру модели, а на объект питоновского класса. (Если кто понимает этот процесс лучше - поправьте)

А еще императивный стиль позволяет создавать и изменять модели "на лету", тем самым давая возможность гибкого использования БД.

Comment: Спасибо, и я дополнил вопрос.))
Почему в последнем (дополнительном) примере обе нотации одновременно? то есть нотация без Table и MetaData более ограниченная, может "не все"?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets дописал свое предположение